# Batch file copy a specific line from conf file to another conf file

Tags: batch-file

using batch file.

in between the `<username>dynamic_username</username>` tag of text1.conf is a dynamic username string. I want it to automatically be selected and copy it to the other file text2.conf and replace the blank tag `<username>insert here username</username>`

text1.conf contains `<username>dynamic_username</username>` <- its on line 19

text2.conf contains `<username></username>` <- its on line 10

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for /f "tokens=2delims=<>" %%i in ('findstr /i "username" "text1.conf"') do set "string=%%i"
(for /f "delims=" %%i in ('findstr /n "^" "text2.conf"') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:*:=!"
    if "!line!" neq "!line:username=!" set "line=%string%"
    echo(!line!
    endlocal
))>"text2.conf.new"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN (text2.conf) DO (
 IF "%%i"=="<username></username>" (
  FINDSTR /b /e ".*<username>.*</username>.*" <text1.conf
  ) ELSE (ECHO(%%i)
)
)>text2.conf.new

FC text2.conf text2.conf.new

GOTO :eof
```

Will delete empty lines though...